# Symfony working with multiple db create Entity for a db

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to work with multiple db in symfony I followed the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html . I had some Entities creates and now I don't know how to use them.

My doctrien.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: 'utf8mb4'
            customers:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMERS)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: 'utf8mb4'
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
                auto_mapping: true
            customers:
                connection: customers
                mappings:
                    Lacoste:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customers'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Customers'
                        alias: Customers
```

If i pass the entity to the folder I want gives this error

> Warning: include(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/vendor/composer/../../src/Entity/Company.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Comment: Your configuration implies that some entities live under Entity/Main and some under Entity/Customers.  Which entity manager do you think Entity/Company.php belongs to?

Comment: Entity/Company belongs to Entity/Main but when I put it under Main gives this error: The class 'App\Entity\Company' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Main

Comment: App\Entity\Main\Company

Comment: I've found the problem in my controller i wasn't accessing the Main folder: use App\Entity\Main\Company;